# javascript for asp.net listview item template

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview

i am trying to implement timer for my listview items.
my javascript is as follow:

```
function countdown() {
var now = new Date();
var biddate = document.getElementById('InitiateDate').value
var kickoff = Date.parse(biddate);
var diff = kickoff - now;

var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
var secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

var dd = days;
var hh = hours - days * 24;
var mm = mins - hours * 60;
var ss = secs - mins * 60;

if (mm<10) {
    mm = "0" + mm;
}
if (ss<10) {
    ss = "0" + ss;
}


document.getElementById("CountDownTimer")
            .innerHTML =
                dd + ':' +
                hh + ':' +
                mm + ':' +
                ss;

if (dd < 0) {
    document.getElementById("CountDownTimer")
            .innerHTML = "time up";
}

}
setInterval('countdown()', 1000);
```

and my listview item template relevant part is:

```
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="InitiateDate" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("InitiateDate") %>'  ReadOnly="True"  ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <div id="CountDownTimer" class="timer"> </div>
    </td>
```

this javascript is working fine but only for the first row of the listview.i need it to work for all rows and will give the the countdown timer for each row.

Comment: not yet..still looking

Comment: where u call javascript? How u trigger to call?

Comment: is it any button click?

Comment: no, the javascript is in different document with link `<script src="scripts/timer_listview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the ASP page. i want it to run all the time after page load.

Comment: ok just wait i will update the answer...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved It! with little change to Tick function.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer time = (Timer)sender;
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)time.Parent; 

    foreach (ListViewItem listItem in Listview1.Items)
    {
        Label InitiateDate = item.FindControl("InitiateDate") as Label;
        HtmlGenericControl CountDownTimer = item.FindControl("CountDownTimer") as HtmlGenericControl;
        if (CountDownTimer.InnerHtml != "time up")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(InitiateDate, this.GetType(), "AKey" + item.DataItemIndex, "countdown(" + InitiateDate.ClientID + " ," + CountDownTimer.ClientID + ");", true);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks a lot man. hope to see you in other problems:)

Comment: just to mention that it works in Chrome and EE. in firefox the function runs only 1 time..

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            TextBox InitiateDate = e.Item.FindControl("InitiateDate") as TextBox;
            HtmlGenericControl CountDownTimer = e.Item.FindControl("CountDownTimer") as HtmlGenericControl;

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(InitiateDate, this.GetType(), "myscript", "countdown('"+ InitiateDate.ClientID +"', '"+ CountDownTimer.ClientID +"');", true);
        }
    }
```

script as \

```
    function countdown(InitiateDate,CountDownTimer) {
..
..
var biddate = document.getElementById(InitiateDate).value
..
..

document.getElementById(CountDownTimer).innerHTML=dd + ':' +
            hh + ':' +
            mm + ':' +
            ss;
}
```

Comment: how can i add this event to my listview? in the javascript isnt it supposed to be `var biddate = document.getElementById('InitiateDate').value`?

Comment: I have passed the clientId of InitiateDate into the javascript function. Then we can achieve the document.getElementById(InitiateDate).value without 'InitiateDate'

Comment: protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)

Comment: i have error in this line `if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)` error:`Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemType' and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType'`

Comment: if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem )

Comment: if this ans helped u dnt forgt to mark as answer...

Comment: i got an error: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` form line : `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(InitiateDate, this.GetType(), "myscript", "countdown('" + InitiateDate.ClientID + "', '" + CountDownTimer.ClientID + "');", true);` and what is `"myscript"`?

Comment: myscript is the id of the script

Comment: check with CountDownTimer and InitiateDate control values. add runat="server" to the control div

Comment: again it is working only for the first row but now the timer is not active but freeze time...

Comment: i m working on the code. just wait i will give u the complete code

Comment: i worked this much.. pls have a look on it

Comment: thanks for your efforts...but now only the last one is working:(  i am hopeless with this issue..it seams like the script can work with only one item of the listview.is it correct?

Comment: i want to look on the code. bt no time now. this is the concept. add an alert at the topmost position to check how many times it called by the list

Comment: hi felix, from what i sow on debuging , the parameters are initializes but `SetTime(biddate)` function was called only for the last row in the list.

Comment: yes thats because of the RegisterStartupScript method. it will create the script at the end of the code. we need to follow another method.

Comment: hope we can solve it...i am still trying to find the solution.

Comment: i tried it all night with no solution...

Comment: I hv tried with ajax update panel and timer inside listview. then javascript is fired. pls check with it. i will give u my sample code

Comment: sorry but again only the last item is working.all other get "Timer" text.. is it works for you?

Comment: again from debugging i can see in the script that the parameters are initializes but `SetTime(biddate)` function was called only for the last row in the list.

Comment: jst look this code i will update the last answer.

Comment: i have tried it but now no timers at all :(

Comment: have u added script manager, update panel, timer, triggers?

Comment: i think that if you will solve it i will give you a gold medal.. programming medal of course.

Comment: </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers> 
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1"  runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

Comment: <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  >
        </asp:ScriptManager>
   .......................................................

Comment: i added as you wrote.the previous one worked with the last item and this one doesn't work.

Comment: instead of `Text='<%# Eval ("datetime") %>'` i change to `Text='<%# Eval ("InitiateDate") %>'` in Label control to retrieve the relevant data. all other code was taken from you answer.

Comment: i will give u my entire code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem )
        {
            Label InitiateDate = e.Item.FindControl("InitiateDate") as Label;
            HtmlGenericControl CountDownTimer = e.Item.FindControl("CountDownTimer") as HtmlGenericControl;

           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(InitiateDate, this.GetType(), "AKey" + e.Item.DataItemIndex, "countdown(" + InitiateDate.ClientID + " ," + CountDownTimer.ClientID + ");", true);
}
    }
```

script

```
var biddate, InitiateDateTemp, CountDownTimerTemp;
    function countdown(InitiateDate, CountDownTimer) {
        InitiateDateTemp = InitiateDate;
        CountDownTimerTemp = CountDownTimer;




      biddate = InitiateDate.innerHTML;

 //   setInterval(function () { SetTime(biddate) }, 1000);

  //  var stopTimer;
    var timerId = setInterval(function () {

       var dd= SetTime(biddate);

       if (dd <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }
    }, 1000);

}

function  SetTime(biddate)  {
    var kickoff = Date.parse(biddate);
    var now = Date.now();
    var diff = kickoff - now;
   // debugger;
    var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
    var secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

    var dd = days;
    var hh = hours - days * 24;
    var mm = mins - hours * 60;
    var ss = secs - mins * 60;

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = "0" + mm;
    }
    if (ss < 10) {
        ss = "0" + ss;
    }


    CountDownTimerTemp.innerHTML =
                     dd + ':' +
                     hh + ':' +
                     mm + ':' +
                     ss;



    if (dd < 0) {
        CountDownTimerTemp
                 .innerHTML = "time up";
        return -1;

    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

datalist label and div

```
  <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
            </asp:DataList>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate >


                    <asp:Label ID="InitiateDate" Text='<%# Eval ("datetime") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>

                    <div id="CountDownTimer" runat="server" >Timer</div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts...but now only the last one is working:(

Answer (score 0):

```
 var biddate, InitiateDateTemp, CountDownTimerTemp;

        function countdown(InitiateDate, CountDownTimer) {
            InitiateDateTemp = InitiateDate;
            CountDownTimerTemp = CountDownTimer;

            biddate = InitiateDate.innerHTML;


               var dd= SetTime(biddate);


        }




        function  SetTime(biddate)  {
            var kickoff = Date.parse(biddate);
            var now = Date.now();
            var diff = kickoff - now;
           // debugger;
            var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
            var secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

            var dd = days;
            var hh = hours - days * 24;
            var mm = mins - hours * 60;
            var ss = secs - mins * 60;

            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = "0" + mm;
            }
            if (ss < 10) {
                ss = "0" + ss;
            }


            CountDownTimerTemp.innerHTML =
                             dd + ':' +
                             hh + ':' +
                             mm + ':' +
                             ss;



            if (dd < 0) {
                CountDownTimerTemp
                         .innerHTML = "time up";
                return -1;

            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }




  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer time = (Timer)sender;
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)time.Parent;
        ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent.Parent ;

        foreach (ListViewItem listItem in lst.Items )
        {

            Label InitiateDate = item.FindControl("InitiateDate") as Label;
            HtmlGenericControl CountDownTimer = item.FindControl("CountDownTimer") as HtmlGenericControl;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(InitiateDate, this.GetType(), "AKey" + item.DataItemIndex, "countdown(" + InitiateDate.ClientID + " ," + CountDownTimer.ClientID + ");", true);

        }

    }
```

on the page load event add this code . this is my test code

```
//very important code.    (if (IsPostBack == false))
  if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            List<A> data = new List<A>();
            A a = new A();
            A a1 = new A();
            a.Leave_Status = "A";
            a.datetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            data.Add(a);
            a1.Leave_Status = "A1";
            a1.datetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

            data.Add(a1);
            ListView1.DataSource = data;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: sorry but again only the last item is working.all other get "Timer" text..

Comment: is this code works for you?

Comment: go with thi code. its the concept. it will work 4 all the rows. bt logic is mistake. pls correct the logic as well.

Comment: worked 4 me. add the updated answer...

Comment: how can i add the data bind? i already bind the listview through datareader.

Comment: its ok. u can add by using datareader. update ur code if possible. i will clear it

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script>


        var biddate, InitiateDateTemp, CountDownTimerTemp;

        function countdown(InitiateDate, CountDownTimer) {
            InitiateDateTemp = InitiateDate;
            CountDownTimerTemp = CountDownTimer;

            biddate = InitiateDate.innerHTML;

            var kickoff = Date.parse(biddate);
            var now = Date.now();
            var diff = kickoff - now;
            //debugger;
            var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
            var secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

            var dd = days;
            var hh = hours - days * 24;
            var mm = mins - hours * 60;
            var ss = secs - mins * 60;

            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = "0" + mm;
            }
            if (ss < 10) {
                ss = "0" + ss;
            }

             if (dd < 0) {
                CountDownTimerTemp
                         .innerHTML = "time up";
            }
            else {
                CountDownTimerTemp.innerHTML =
                            dd + ':' +
                            hh + ':' +
                            mm + ':' +
                            ss;
            }
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  >
        </asp:ScriptManager>



        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <p>

        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:ListView   ID="ListView1" runat="server"   >
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate >
                     <asp:Label   ID="InitiateDate" Text='<%# Eval ("datetime") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>

                   <div id="CountDownTimer" runat="server" >Timer</div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers> 
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1"  runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            List<A> data = new List<A>();
            A a = new A();
            A a1 = new A();
            a.Leave_Status = "A";
            a.datetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            data.Add(a);
            a1.Leave_Status = "A1";
            a1.datetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

            data.Add(a1);
            ListView1.DataSource = data;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }

    }

    class A
    {
        public string Leave_Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime  datetime { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer time = (Timer)sender;
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)time.Parent;
        ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent.Parent ;

        foreach (ListViewItem listItem in lst.Items )
        {

            Label InitiateDate = item.FindControl("InitiateDate") as Label;
            HtmlGenericControl CountDownTimer = item.FindControl("CountDownTimer") as HtmlGenericControl;
            if (CountDownTimer.InnerHtml != "time up")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(InitiateDate, this.GetType(), "AKey" + item.DataItemIndex, "countdown(" + InitiateDate.ClientID + " ," + CountDownTimer.ClientID + ");", true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: check with this answer. it worked 4 me. logic also worked

Comment: you right..your standalone code is working!!!!! thanks.. will try to implement it in my project and will update you.

Comment: ok........... check with ur code...

Comment: i tried to implement it in my project from population the listview through SQL command with datareader and its not working..

Comment: `DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dbServices service = new dbServices("MyConnection");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable", service.SqlCon);
            SqlDataReader drRecord = command.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(drRecord);

            Listview1.DataSource = dt;
            Listview1.DataBind();` when "InitiateDate" is the relevant field with date string.

Comment: check dt.Rows.Count();

Comment: is it inside the page load event? if yes, add  if (IsPostBack == false) block. its very important.

Comment: i added it to the page load with no change...i get all rows from database with all value only in the timer i see "Timer" string instead of countdown timer...will it ever end ?

Comment: add timer value from 1000 to 3000. then check it

Comment: u need not a loop inside javascript. it will loop through timer. the timer will not stop. it will refresh the gridvalue in every second. if network is slow, it will b a burden. So increase the time period and check it

Comment: debugg the page then check whether it will hit on the timerclick event

Comment: why in your code it works and with datareader not?

Comment: AutoEventWireup="true" is it ther in your page?

Comment: i gets warning `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewTableRow' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView'.` while debugging from line `ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent.Parent;`

Comment: ok thats the error. add   ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent.Parent.parent;  then check with debug mode. run on internal browser. then u will get exact error. on chrome, firefox etc the error will not be shown

Comment: where to place `AutoEventWireup="true"`?

Comment: its ok. just do this comment  add ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent.Parent.parent; then check with debug mode. run on internal browser. then u will get exact error. on chrome, firefox etc the error will not be shown

Comment: i am using Chrome explorer.

Comment: its not good. use internal browser for checking the page. its good

Comment: im lvng. c  u tmrw. by check with internal browser...

Comment: worked........................?

Comment: same error with : `ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent.Parent.parent;`

Comment: do you want me to check with firefox?

Comment: check with it ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent;

Comment: give ur complete code in the listview

Comment: save the page and refresh the page. then only updated message is shown

Comment: show the code inside the listview

Comment: i added all my code..just without database table.

Answer (score 0):

script

```
    var biddate, InitiateDateTemp, CountDownTimerTemp;

    function countdown(InitiateDate, CountDownTimer) {
        InitiateDateTemp = InitiateDate;
        CountDownTimerTemp = CountDownTimer;

        biddate = InitiateDate.innerHTML;

        var kickoff = Date.parse(biddate);
        var now = Date.now();
        var diff = kickoff - now;
        //debugger;
        var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
        var secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

        var dd = days;
        var hh = hours - days * 24;
        var mm = mins - hours * 60;
        var ss = secs - mins * 60;

        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = "0" + mm;
        }
        if (ss < 10) {
            ss = "0" + ss;
        }

        if (dd < 0) {
            CountDownTimerTemp
                     .innerHTML = "time up";
        }
        else {
            CountDownTimerTemp.innerHTML =
                        dd + ':' +
                        hh + ':' +
                        mm + ':' +
                        ss;
        }
    }

</script>
```

ASP.net

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<asp:ListView ID="Listview1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="_background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">

                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="field1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("field1") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="field2" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("field2") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="field3" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("field3") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="field4" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("field4") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate >
                 <asp:Label   ID="InitiateDate" Text='<%# Eval ("InitiateDate") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>

               <div id="CountDownTimer" runat="server" >Timer</div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers> 
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1"  runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" class="ListViewLayoutTable">
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                            <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" class="ListViewLayoutTable"
                                style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
                                    <th id="Th7" runat="server">
                                        field1</th>
                                    <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                                        field2</th>
                                    <th id="Th2" runat="server">
                                        field3</th>
                                    <th id="Th3" runat="server">
                                        field4</th>
                                    <th id="Th4" runat="server">
                                        timer</th>

                                </tr>
                                <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Shops : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dbServices service = new dbServices("MyConnection");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", service.SqlCon);
        SqlDataReader drRecord = command.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(drRecord);

        ShopBidsTable.DataSource = dt;
        ShopBidsTable.DataBind();
    }

}


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer time = (Timer)sender;
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)time.Parent.Parent;
    ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent.Parent.Parent;

    foreach (ListViewItem listItem in lst.Items)
    {

        Label InitiateDate = item.FindControl("InitiateDate") as Label;
        HtmlGenericControl CountDownTimer = item.FindControl("CountDownTimer") as HtmlGenericControl;
        if (CountDownTimer.InnerHtml != "time up")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(InitiateDate, this.GetType(), "AKey" + item.DataItemIndex, "countdown(" + InitiateDate.ClientID + " ," + CountDownTimer.ClientID + ");", true);
        }
    }

}

class A
{
    public string Leave_Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
}
}
```

this is all my code...

Comment: oh my god just change from ListView lst = (ListView)time.Parent.Parent.Parent;

    foreach (ListViewItem listItem in lst.Items) to foreach (ListViewItem listItem in ListView1.Items)

Comment: yes.just like this.now it works with both EE and Chrome bu not in Firefox.in Firefox it runs for the first time and from the second iteration it gets "Timer" string.

Comment: but still you saved me...thanks.